# How to show the charts(linear) using Plotly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, charts, plotly

I am using the below the script in python:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from plotly.plotly.plotly import image
X=[1,2,3]
Y=[1,2,3]
fig = {'data': [{'x': X, 'y': Y, 'type': 'bar'}]}
#iplot([{"x": X, "y": Y}])
image.ishow(fig, 'png', scale=3)
```

I started **ipython-notebook** in ubuntu-PC also,but I am not able to visualize the image created or the chart plotted.
The Output is coming like this when I uncommented iplot statement: 
          
and it returns **raise exceptions.PlotlyError(return_data['error'])
KeyError: 'error** .
 How to plot the using plot and how to see that?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is you haven't told plotly to work in notebook mode with:

```
init_notebook_mode()
```

You imported it but never ran it.

From: https://plot.ly/python/offline/